# Combining mod_rewrite and basic auth via .htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, basic-authentication

I have a WordPress site which is using the seo friendly urls. For this, some mod_rewrite rules where defined. Now I need to add extra security to a single file via the .htaccess file (only possibility). This is what I came up with:

```
AuthUserFile /home/mysite/.htpasswds/.htpasswd
AuthName "mysite.com"
AuthType Basic

<files "somefile.php">
  require valid-user
</files>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^somefile\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

The WordPress site is still working fine, but if I try to access my secure page, it's looping redirects, which results after a while in a too many redirects message. I never got the login box.

If I remove the rewrite part, the security is working just fine. But in that case, my site is not working as it should.

Can anyone help me with this one?

Thanks!